# What does the output_expression for "DELETE FROM table" do?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I recently ran across an oddity. The following is valid SQL:

```
DELETE FROM customer *;
```

The documentation for PostgreSQL [DELETE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-delete.html) says the star is a possible value for the `output_expression`:

> An expression to be computed and returned by the DELETE command after
>   each row is deleted. The expression can use any column names of the
>   table or table(s) listed in USING. Write * to return all columns.

I tried it with and without the star and can't see a difference. In fact, I can put just about anything single word after the table name and it is accepted. It doesn't even have to be an actual column name. Nothing extra is returned.

```
db=> DELETE FROM customer wheeeeeee;
DELETE 19
```

So what does it do and what could I use it for?

Question [also posted on the PostgreSQL mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/E1TDAj3-0008JO-V0@wrigleys.postgresql.org).

Comment: I did. It just deletes the rows and returns nothing special.

Comment: Looks like you missed `RETURNING` which is a non optional part of the grammar preceding `output_expression` I presume that `*` is just treated as an alias (as for `wheeeeeee`) without that.

Comment: I've deleted my answer along those lines as I'm not actually sure that `*` is treated as an alias. It isn't possible to then use it in a `WHERE` clause and with the optional `AS` keyword, i.e. `DELETE FROM customer AS *` fails with a syntax error.

Comment: @MartinSmith, after reading your analysis (now deleted), I tend to think it's a bug in Postgres. The * is being treated as an alias, although an illegal one. The grammar for the RETURNING clause appears to be incorrect -- at least in the documentation. I'm going to report it as a bug and see what the devs say.

Comment: @BarryBrown - From experimentation I think the token is maybe being accepted as though it were an alias in that specific query but it doesn't actually get treated as an alias in any way. `DELETE FROM customer * WHERE customer.id=1` works. If it was treated as an alias at all then referencing `customer` should fail as it would be hidden. Seems to be behaviour specific to `*` as well. Trying `+` for example fails. Without looking at the source code not sure exactly what is going on.

Comment: I took a look at parse.y and scan.l in the source and can't figure out exactly which rule is matching the `*`. If it's a table alias, it must be matched by `ColID`, but `ColID` just reduces to `IDENT` and that's where the trail runs cold.

Comment: Tom Lane explains this on the PostgreSQL mailing list in reply to the repost of this question there. See http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/5536.1347854286@sss.pgh.pa.us . I added the link to @MichalPolitowski's answer to make sure nobody misses it.

Answer (score 5):

The asterisk is **not** output_expression, for this you would have to use the `RETURNING` keyword. It is instead an old, obsolete  syntax for including child tables in queries. (The last version for which it is documented seems to be [PostgreSQL 8.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-inherit.html). Since the syntax is still valid it is a documentation bug, as Tom Lane points out in the post linked below.)

Since PostgreSQL 7.1 this is the default (unless [sql_inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-SQL-INHERITANCE) is set to off) and the `ONLY` keyword is used for the opposite, so the * is not very useful.

See [this explanatory post from Tom Lane on the PostgreSQL mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/5536.1347854286@sss.pgh.pa.us).